# Retrieve array based on ids of another array

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, set, sequence

I have two arrays of users and beams

```
struct User {
   var id: Int
   var jobTitle: String
 }

struct Beams {
 var isSelected = false
 var id: Int
 var userIds: [Int]
}
```

If the user selects a particular beam, all the users which are assigned to that beam will be selected of the first array. The user can select multiple beams and i am getting the data from api response, and i have to send the selected users in a post call. so i have to select all the selected users from an array of beams and on the basis of filtered ids, send that array in a post call. initially i am filtering all the beams which are selected like this

`beams.filter { $0.isSelected }.compactMap { $0.userIDS }`

which gives me an array of [Int]. These are the userIds which have to be sent. I somehow can't figure out how will i select these particular ids from my array of users which contains other attributes as well. contains can be used to filter one element but not a sequence. and even if i filter or take an intersection of these ids and my userArray. i am still left with a set or an array of ids. from which i'd have to generate my array, i want to keep all the other attributes as well. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. I have something of this nature in my mind

```
   let selectedBeamsIds = beams.filter { $0.isSelected }.compactMap { $0.userIDS }
   users.append(selectedBeamsIds.compactMap { getUniqueUsersForBeams(ids: $0) } )

  private func getUniqueUsersForBeams(ids: [Int]) -> [User] {

    let ower = users.reduce(into: [User]()) { (result, 
     user) in

      let filteredUserIds = ids.filter { $0 == user.id }
        //result.append(use)

    }
}
```

I also need to do this with another array of jobTitles which is like

```
struct JobTitle {
 var jobTitle: String
 var isSelected = false
 }
```

this one is straight forward as if the users's jobTitle matches with the selected items of [String] array then select that user to be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
let selectedIds = beams.filter { (beams) -> Bool in
    beams.isSelected
}.flatMap { (beams) -> [Int] in
    beams.userIds
}

let filteredUsers = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    selectedIds.contains(user.id)
}
```

1 ) Filter out selected beams

2 ) Collect all the userIds in the selected beams

3 ) Filter users by checking if the id is present in the previously collected ids.

Comment: thank you @subramanian, converting to one array instead of a 2d array makes sense.

Comment: Do accept the answer if you find it helpful. Cheers. :)